# How to Disable Right Click on wordpress Dashboard(Admin Area)

Tags: plugins

Just want to know how to disable right click on dashboard(admin area) side of the wordpress.already used following code for frontend(user area).

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selector `.wp-admin` to make sure you are selecting only the wordpress admin area.

```
html body.wp-admin {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

The code above will prevent the user from selecting/highlighting the page content.

If you really want to disable right click, just use a simple JS code like:

```
<script>
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("alert('Right click is blocked.'); return false");
</script>
```

References:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: thanks for the answer @filipecsweb.it worked  .Also is it possible to prevent ctrl+u and ctrl+f using the same kind of code.

Comment: I'm afraid not with one line of code. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597224/how-to-hide-html-source-disable-right-click-and-text-copy and check if you can enlighten yourself.